# Strange behavior adding view to sharedapplication in TabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

Hello i have a problem with the view i added to the sharedapplciation here is how i added the view:

```
if (!thingLocator) {
    thingLocator = [[AWThingLocatorController alloc] init];
}
//show the view
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:thingLocator.view];
```

and the result it gives me is something like this:

[image: Result of adding the view]

As you can see the top and the bottom of the view is getting cut, thx in advance

Comment: never worked with that controller, but is it possible to change the frame of it? Because now it looks like it's centered in the space between the status bar and tab bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how i fix it, it appears that the view was getting drawn at (0,0) and ignoring the status bar...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
}
```